# Implementing Document-based Applications with CoreAnimation Layers

Tags: macos, cocoa, design-patterns, cocoa-design-patterns

I am working on a diagram drawing application that is based on *CoreAnimation* framework. I have a common functionality set that includes: creating diagram objects, editing their geometrical properties, moving them around, etc. Each object is represented as a separate `CALayer` (or a group of layers).

My application is also document-based which means I am following the design imposed by Cocoa for document management.

Here is an example of what the application looks like:

[image http://guitar.rizo.me/views/main.view/image3.png](http://guitar.rizo.me/views/main.view/image3.png)

Although I do understand the fundamental principles of how the things should work I can't figure out how to make a clear design separation between the model/view implementations.

- Is `CALayer` class a view class or I can also view it as a model (since its properties are the only part of the application's data)?
- What would be the ideal organization for such an application given the document-based architecture?

I can't see any clean way to solve this design problem, what would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.